# Is there a way to delete grouped images in Darktable

Tags: darktable

I'm using Darktable to review and edit my photos. For this, I always import RAW and JPG at the same time, which are automatically grouped by Darktable. During the review process, I usually use the grouped view (activated `G`) so that I don't have to review each image twice.

When I decide that I don't like a photo and mark it as rejected (by pressing [R]) only the RAW image is marked. As a result, trashing the rejected images will only delete the marked RAW images, while the JPGs remain in Darktable.

Is there a way to automatically delete the JPG files, too? E.g., is there a way to either mark the whole group or delete a group with a rejected image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, as far as I know, there isn't. There's an [issue filed years ago](https://redmine.darktable.org/issues/9785) about this, you could bump it up for renewed discussion, since it seems to have some support.

Comment: This was not the answer that I was hoping for, but enough to find a solution. The script [contrib/rate_group.lua](https://github.com/darktable-org/lua-scripts/blob/master/contrib/rate_group.lua) in darktable's github repository does exactly what I want.

Comment: The issue link (https://redmine.darktable.org/issues/9785) no longer seems to work. It seems like Darktable issue tracking has moved to github but I didn't find this issue listed. Has it been copied over?